# "Unable to find a userdata.img file for ABI armeabi..."

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

Once again I've made the mistake of updating Eclipse with the latest Android SDK/tools and have rendered it useless.

Running Eclipse on a Mac.

When I try to create an AVD it tells me it is "unable to find a userdata.img file for ABI armeabi". I've read all the similar questions here that tell me to go to Run/Run Configurations and make sure I have the latest "ARM EABI v7a System Image" downloaded. I've done that. I've restarted my machine. Still no joy.

FWIW I'm not trying to create a 4.x emulator; just 2.3.3. UPDATE: I can successfully create a 2.2 emulator with all the same parameters (screen size, storage card size, memory, etc.) as I was trying for 2.3.3. Also, I can successfully create a 4.x emulator with those parameters. Just not 2.3.3.

Again, I've read all the similar questions. Doing what I did seems to have solved the problem for several developers running Win7. Other questions end with someone saying, "I'm downloading the file now" but no update as to whether it worked or not. In my case, after downloading the file I see no change in behavior.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Manually download ARM EABI for android 4.3 from here and it solves! https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sysimg_armv7a-18_r01.zip

Comment: Close the emulator and wipe the emulator data.

Answer (score 38):

[image]

Check the highlighted part is installed or not..

if it is installed you can find this under CPU.. Select it and click create avd

[image]

Comment: For me the armeabi was installed but still gave errors. I had an uninstall + reinstall and then it fixed itself.

Answer (score 17):

Step 1) Open Eclipse and click on Run Configurations (pull down the arrow next to the Run or Debug button).

Step 2) Select "Android Application" and click "New"

Step 3) Select the "Target" tab and select "Automatic" (Click once more even it is selected and the list box below is disabled"

Step 4) Click on the "Manager..." button

Step 5) In all the "Android 4.0.X" sections, select "ARM EABI v7a System Image" checkbox

Step 6) Click the "Install X Package..." button

Reference: http://tech.thecoolblogs.com/2012/01/unable-to-find-userdataimg-file-for-abi.html#ixzz1u2EMZGt7

Answer (score 12):

This error is happening because the location of userdata.img file has changed since Android 4 (API Level 14). So we need to reinstall the ARM EABI package. Follow the steps given at 
http://tech.thecoolblogs.com/2012/01/unable-to-find-userdataimg-file-for-abi.html

Answer (score 12):

Install the ARM EABI img from the sdk manager for android 4.0 your problem will be solved

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and this is how I solved it:

In Eclipse:

1. Window > Android SDK Manager
2. Select ARM EABI v7a System Image
3. Install package
4. Done.  You should be able to create your AVD now.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 6):

Now with Android 4.1 (API 16), make sure you install the ARM EABI v7a System Image in the Android SDK Manager. This works perfectly in Eclipse Indigo on Mac OSX.

Comment: Thank you for posting this, I probably wouldn't have figured this out otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you still need to install ***Google USB Driver*** in Extras in the bottom of Android SDK manager.

Answer (score 2):

Solved a problem after I realized that newly created `AVDs` were being saved in user folder (user `foo`) `C:\HOME\foo` and Android plugin was trying to find them in `C:\Users\foo`.

I have set environment variable (this will change save avd folder).

```
ANDROID_SDK_HOM=C:\Users\foo
```

*Make sure you create your AVD again since you have changed save location now.*

That solved a problem, I assume the proper way would be to set look-up folder but could not figure out how to change that.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same erorr, even after deleting and re-installing that package. I looked at the sdk folder, and found that the images were all the way under

`...\sdk\system-images\android-10\x86\images\x86`

Looking at thow the PAI 17 images were stored, I copied everything in that directory and moved it to

`...\sdk\system-images\android-10\x86`

Now it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved from command line by running:

```
update sdk -u -a -t android-16,sysimg-16
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using the command line.

I fix it by copying the files under

```
...\sdk\system-images\android-X\armeabi-vY\
```

into

```
...\sdk\platforms\android-X\images
```

Maybe you need to create first the folder images

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related to ["No system images installed for this target" even though Image is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886706/no-system-images-installed-for-this-target-even-though-image-is-installed).

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22196010/492336), I moved `c:\adt\sdk\system-images\android-23\default\x86` up one folder to `c:\adt\sdk\system-images\android-23\x86`, and after that I got the error:

```
Unable to find a userdata.img file for ABI armeabi...
```

On a hunch, I created a symlink/junction to the original folder, and it worked. I used this:

```
mklink /j "c:\adt\sdk\system-images\android-23\default\x86" "c:\adt\sdk\system-images\android-23\x86"
```

It's just that you need it in both folders. I used a junction instead of simply copying the folder so as not to waste space.