# Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I install latest Android SDK on window7 system, when I am trying to create Emulator it's responding "Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder"
folder.

any one have idea/suggeation over this?

Comment: duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086630/unable-to-find-a-userdata-img-file-for-abi-armeabi

Comment: Window -->Android SDK Manager -->Select ARM EABI v7a System Image -->Install package

Answer (score 0):

thanks ...but I was forget to choose CPU/ABI option while create emulator...It solved my problem.[image]