# android 4 my first app development

Tags: android

When i try to create a virtual device in eclipse I get the following error
    Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder.
My SDK manager shows that the ARM EABI v7 system image is already installed. I am using Windows XP OS and eclipse juno version please help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Unable to find a userdata.img file for ABI armeabi..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086630/unable-to-find-a-userdata-img-file-for-abi-armeabi)

Answer (score 0):

It is usual thing if you have russian letters in path to your AVD folder

For example your Windows Username

Comment: How do I get to know the path to my AVD folder?

Comment: Ussualy eclipse print it when error. Show me full error trace

Comment: I am really sorry but I am quite lost and I dont know how to do what you are asking me to do

Comment: [2012-11-03 11:14:31 - SDK Manager] Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder.

Comment: Mayby you really download not all packeges

Comment: i have installed all the packages that were selected by default. did not deselect anything did not make any changes

Answer (score 0):

Try to install "ARM EABI v7a System Image" from SDK manager and create again your virtual device. Source [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com.es/2011/10/error-in-creating-emulator-for-android.html).

Comment: Actually the latest android version in the SDK manager is android 4.1.2 and I have installed all the packages needed for it.Do I still have to install the ARM EABI v7a System image for android 4.0?

Comment: Yes, I think is required to run virtual devices. Give it a try.

Comment: but ARM EABI v7a System image is already installed for 4.1.2 also.I ll install for 4.0 also and try

Comment: is it better to download the packages for 4.0 than downloading the packages of 4.1.2?

Comment: Download all ARM EABI v7a for all versions you want to run a virtual device. Create the new virtual device again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a new AVD