# Cannot create 2.3.3 Intel Atom AVD (userdata.img not found)

Tags: android, eclipse

I have read all relevant questions and no solution has worked form me (["Unable to find a userdata.img file for ABI armeabi..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086630/unable-to-find-a-userdata-img-file-for-abi-armeabi))

I can create/run Intel Atom AVD's under 4.2.2 without a problem.

But when i choose 2.3.3 as the target, i get the following console error:

```
[2013-02-16 20:44:04 - SDK Manager] Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI x86 to copy into the AVD folder.
```

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling the Intel image without success.

I'm using Android Developer Tools Build: v21.1.0-569685

[image]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I searched for the answer to this and after coming up empty handed, I researched what files were being installed/deleted when adding/removing SDK levels through the manager.

This worked for me. It's a bug w/ the android-10 x86 system images folder location. I discovered it by comparing w/ the other versions that do work like android-17.

I copied the files from the folder

> <sdk>/system-images/android-10/**x86/images/x86**

to the correct folder

> <sdk>/system-images/android-10/**x86**

I didn't try to delete any existing files, I just merged the files in w/ the existing files that are there.

(this was on a Mac btw)

Comment: I just tried this, and it works :). Thanks!. I cant believe information for this is so scarce on the net. Debugging on an ARM image is a PITA!

Comment: @jross Your answer has just saved my day!

Comment: fyi, I had to disable the "Use host GPU" option for Mac OSX

Comment: Very good! Mac here too and couldn't find solution elsewhere!

Comment: I also confirm for Arch Linux.

Comment: This workaround was needed for revision 1 of the image, as of revision 2 **it is not needed anymore**. See Ralf's answer below.

Answer (score 7):

*This workaround was needed for revision 1 of the image, as of revision 2 **it is not needed anymore**. See Ralf's answer below.*

Apparently the x86 system image for android-10 (as downloaded from Android SDK Manager) installs some files in the wrong place.

You can make it work by creating symlinks in `<sdk root>/system-images/android-10/x86/` pointing to all files in `<sdk root>/system-images/android-10/x86/images/x86/`.

This should work on any Unix system (tested on Linux):

```
cd $ANDROID_HOME/system-images/android-10/x86/
for F in `ls images/x86/`; do ln -s images/x86/$F; done
```

where `$ANDROID_HOME` points to your SDK installation.

Answer (score 5):

After noticing the issue listed here, we fixed the system-image on the SDK repository. If you open the SDK Manager and install revision 2 of the Intel x86 System-Image for API 10, it should now work properly without having to move files around.
Despite the packaging issue, the system-image is the same.
The emulator will indicate "Android 2.3.7" (both Android 2.3.3 and 2.3.7 are API 10.)

Answer (score 0):

Install Atom x86 System Image manually. You can find right image and detailed installation instructions [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/alternate-method-installing-the-intel-atom-android-x86-emulator-image-manually), but first remove old x86 Image from Android SDK Manager. It worked for Me.

Comment: The intel link only has "From the Android* 2.3.7" images.