# Android arrow keys on a Mac

Tags: android

My teacher wants us to work on the Snake Android demo, and I'm having trouble using the arrow keys of my Mac. I need to press the arrow about 20 times before the snake actually moves. In my 2.3.3 AVD config I have enabled `hw.dPad` and `hw.keyboard`. One thing I was suggested was to use an Android 4 rom, but I actually get worse problems. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are using the emulator.
It is indeed pretty slow on old/moderate hardware.

One good solution is to use a x86 Android image instead of the default one, they are notably more efficient. 
installation guide : http://bryanmarty.com/blog/2012/08/04/faster-android-emulator-mac-android-4-0-3-ice-cream-sandwich-2-3-3-gingerbread/

Another is to run the game directly on your terminal if you own an Android phone/tablet.

Comment: MUCH faster, thanks! I had heard about this x86 image thing, but I had had another bug in the process. I tried again thanks to your answer and this time I solved it with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913852/cannot-create-2-3-3-intel-atom-avd-userdata-img-not-found

Comment: Thank you Google for the HOURS it took to set up a more or less working development environment... If it wasn't for SO's rules I would have a lot of things to say about this whole Android development thing... And by the way my hardware is up to date.

Comment: That makes me very curious of what hurdles you encountered but it is indeed not really the place for this.