# "No system images installed for this target" even though Image is installed

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

[image: SDK Manager]

So I'm trying to create an AVD Simulator, and I keep getting the "No system images installed for this target" error when trying to create a 4.2.2 system even though the image is installed (See picture of SDK Manager).

My system is x64, does that make a difference?

[image: Eclipse Error]

Answer (score 56):

After SDK Update I had the same problems with API Level 19 and 
in my case restarting eclipse didn't solve it.

For some reason, in the `sdk/system-images/android-19` directory, sub-folders with system images (armeabi-v7a and x86) were placed within `"default"` directory. 
I just moved them into `android-19` directory (if eclipse is running at the same time, you will have to restart it).

Comment: It's under /Users/username/ on mac by the way.

Comment: I don't have a `sdk/system-images/` folder, but I do have `sdk/platforms/`

Comment: This worked for me as well!  But I had the problem when using API 21 so the folder was android-21. Thanks again!

Comment: This didn't quite work for me. Moving the armeabi-v71 folder to its parent folder allows AVD manager to recognize it, but it can't create a device. It says "Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi-v71 to copy into the AVD folder" even though there is a 2GB userdata.img file in that folder. (trying to install 4.3/API-18 and use with Visual Studio/Xamarin)

Answer (score 12):

You just need to restart the tools.  I have seen this bug before.  The appropriate installed images will show up after the restart.

You can also try to refresh within the 'Packages' menu, but the easiest thing, is to restart the tools.

Comment: Do you mean restart Eclipse? beacuse I've tried it and no luck :(

Comment: Yes, I mean restart Eclipse.  This worked for me yesterday.  Did you try the 'Reload' button in the 'Packages' Menu (my other answer?)

Comment: It worked for me when I restarted Windows OS and launched the AVD manager again.

Answer (score 9):

Goto **sdk\system-images** and open the folder of the current API you are using (eg.**android-19** folder in your case).
Now you'll find a folder named **'default'**, open it and you'll see the folder named **'armeabi-v7a'** or which ever system image you've installed.
Now move the folder **'armeabi-v7a'** to the directory **sdk\system-images**...i.e simply out of the **'default'** folder.

That's it.
I had the same problem and this method worked for me. :D

Answer (score 5):

I restart eclipse.it worked out for me,issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this same issue. My problem was solved by killing eclipse (Command + Q) because I'm a Mac user. So, if you're under other operative system be sure to kill the Eclipse's process and relaunch it.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of potentially useful answers here, but none of them were worked for me.

On my Mac, I have both Android Studio and Visual Studio installed. One would hope that they would automatically look for an Android SDK in the same place, but no, not necessarily.

In Android Studio, go to Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager. In the window that pops up, make a note of the Android SDK Location. It should be something like

> /Users/[user]/Library/Android/sdk

Next, in Visual Studio, go to Tools -> SDK Manager. In the window that pops up, the path that should be selected on the left is Projects -> SDK Location -> Android. On the right, click the Locations tab. For me, the Android SDK Location path was set to something like

> /Users/[user]/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx

I changed this to the path that Android Studio was using, and that fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. I restarted Eclipse, reloaded my project and when creating a new emulator, the problem is gone

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread when I did a search on Google for the same error.

So I just wanted to add that if anyone comes across this thread but you are using **Android Studio**. You only have to restart the Android Studio. I did and now I can see what I installed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have rights to all the files in the `android-sdk-linux` directory using:

```
sudo chown $USER -R ./android-sdk-linux
```