# Can't create AVD with Google APIS 19 with CPU Intel even though i have downloaded the image

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-x86, intel-atom

My SDK manager shows:

[image]

I can create AVD with the non Google API image :

[image]

But cannot create a AVD with Google APIs of Intel CPU even though I have it downloaded:

[image]

I have HAXM installed and working.

Comment: whats the prob?? the OK option is not being shown i guess..

Comment: No Ok button is being shown but the CPU option is only ARM although i have downloaded Intel Atom Emulators and Google APIS X86 System image.It should show as it is showing in second screen but its not showing

Comment: you can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15886706/3879470