# Why Android Virtual Device issue

Tags: android, eclipse, virtual, device, android-virtual-device

I am new in android development. I installed Android ADT Bundle for windows. But, when i wanted to setup the Android Virtual Device it shows the "***[2014-09-07 13:51:29 - SDK Manager] Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi-v7a to copy into the AVD folder.***" message. what to do?

Comment: in `sdk manager` you need install system image for your API

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Unable to find a userdata.img file for ABI armeabi..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086630/unable-to-find-a-userdata-img-file-for-abi-armeabi)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the neccessary packages in the sdk Manager, for example for API Level 19 the "SDK Platform" and one of these two "ARM EABI v7a System Image" and "Intel x86 Atom System Image" or both is the minimum requirement to create an AVD that runs on API Level 19

I hope this helps you :)

John